# Using Global Query Filters for all entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, global-query-filter

I have recently found global filters, which is great because I have been tasked with implementing soft deletes in my applicaiton.
Currently I have done this:

```
// Query filters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters
modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasQueryFilter(m => !m.Deleted);
modelBuilder.Entity<Attribute>().HasQueryFilter(m => !m.Deleted);
modelBuilder.Entity<Brand>().HasQueryFilter(m => !m.Deleted);
modelBuilder.Entity<BrandAddress>().HasQueryFilter(m => !m.Deleted);
modelBuilder.Entity<BrandCategory>().HasQueryFilter(m => !m.Deleted);
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasQueryFilter(m => !m.Deleted);
// many more entity types....
```

All the entities inherit a `BaseModel` which looks like this:

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Guid UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to add the query filter for any class that inherits the `BaseModel`?
Something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BaseModel>().HasQueryFilter(m => !m.Deleted);
```

So I don't forget (at a later date) to add the query filter for models I add?

Comment: Yes, using reflexion to search all non abstract child class of BaseModel and then call a constructed generic method for each of them in a loop, while checking this chlid class is managed by the model builder (else not constructt nor call).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For the latest EF Core version (should work for 3.0 also, for earlier versions expression replacement should be handled manually, see `ReplacingExpressionVisitor` call) you can automate it using some [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) (minimal amount of it), [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) and [`IMutableModel.GetEntityTypes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.imutablemodel.getentitytypes?view=efcore-5.0) in your `OnModelCreating` method. Something like this should work:

```
// define your filter expression tree
Expression<Func<BaseModel, bool>> filterExpr = bm => !bm.Deleted;
foreach (var mutableEntityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    // check if current entity type is child of BaseModel
    if (mutableEntityType.ClrType.IsAssignableTo(typeof(BaseModel)))
    {
        // modify expression to handle correct child type
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(mutableEntityType.ClrType);
        var body = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(filterExpr.Parameters.First(), parameter, filterExpr.Body);
        var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);

        // set filter
        mutableEntityType.SetQueryFilter(lambdaExpression);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `IsAssignableTo` is from autofac? I changed it to IsAssignableFrom and it compiles, but it doesn't appear to work (as all my unit tests are now failing)

Comment: @r3plica no, it is from [`Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignableto?view=net-5.0), it was introduced with .NET 5. If you want/need to change it to `IsAssignableFrom` you will need to change the "order" in the if condition: `typeof(BaseModel).IsAssignableFrom(mutableEntityType.ClrType)`

Comment: Ok; when I use it as you have, it complains that `'Type' does not contain a definition for 'IsAssignableTo' and no accessible extension method 'IsAssignableTo' accepting a first argument of type 'Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: But using IsAssignableFrom works :) `if (!typeof(BaseModel).IsAssignableFrom(mutableEntityType.ClrType)) continue;`

Answer (score 8):

You need to construct a lambda expression at runtime for:

```cs
instance => !instance.IsDeleted
```

Now, assume we have this interface, and a number of entities that implement this interface (directly or transitively):

```cs
interface ISoftDelete
{
    bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

class Product : ISoftDelete
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

We want to apply soft-delete query filter to all entities that implement this interface.

To find all entities registered in a DbContext model, we can use `IMutableModel.GetEntityTypes()`. Then we filter all entities implementing `ISoftDelete` and add set a custom query filter.

Here's an extension method that you can use directly:

```cs
internal static class SoftDeleteModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static ModelBuilder ApplySoftDeleteQueryFilter(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            if (!typeof(ISoftDelete).IsAssignableFrom(entityType.ClrType))
            {
                continue;
            }

            var param = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "entity");
            var prop = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, nameof(ISoftDelete.IsDeleted));
            var entityNotDeleted = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Equal(prop, Expression.Constant(false)), param);

            entityType.SetQueryFilter(entityNotDeleted);
        }

        return modelBuilder;
    }
}
```

Now, we can use this in our DbContext:

```cs
class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    // ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>();
        modelBuilder.ApplySoftDeleteQueryFilter(); // <-- must come after all entity definitions
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, What if the type of our property is Guid (like tenantId or so on) instead of boolean property, how should we convert to code you wrote above?

Comment: @tiakham that should be done outside of `OnModelCreating`, because tenant usually changes per request, so it makes sense to apply that filter within a request-scoped context. Having a generic extension method could help there
 `dbContext.Products.ForTenant(id)...`

Comment: thank you for reply. actually, i thought, i could manipulate the context after switch tenant but if there is no tenant id ,i got error and couldnt manipulate it. as you write, i should be done outsite of onmodelcreating, can you give more detail or some example if you have as you can how to be done outside of the scope please?

Comment: now after thinking a bit, i got what you mean man. you mean to write an extension for tenant. it makes sense. cool.

Answer (score 2):

This is generic implementaion of `ApplyQueryFilter`. It accepts any base entity and applies filter to them. It also preserve previously applied filters, so they can be combined.

No magic strings, just statically typed expressions:

```cs
modelBuilder.ApplyQueryFilter<BaseModel>(e => !e.IsDeleted);

// or if soft delete is controlled by interface
modelBuilder.ApplyQueryFilter<ISoftDelete>(e => !e.IsDeleted);
```

And implemenation:

```cs
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void ApplyQueryFilter<TBaseEntity>(this ModelBuilder builder,
        Expression<Func<TBaseEntity, bool>> filter)
    {
        var acceptableItems = builder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
            .Where(et => typeof(TBaseEntity).IsAssignableFrom(et.ClrType))
            .ToList();

        foreach (var entityType in acceptableItems)
        {
            var entityParam = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "e");

            // replacing parameter with actual type
            var filterBody = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(filter.Parameters[0], entityParam, filter.Body);

            var filterLambda = entityType.GetQueryFilter();
            // Other filter already present, combine them
            if (filterLambda != null)
            {
                filterBody = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(entityParam, filterLambda.Parameters[0], filterBody);
                filterBody = Expression.AndAlso(filterLambda.Body, filterBody);
                filterLambda = Expression.Lambda(filterBody, filterLambda.Parameters);
            }
            else
            {
                filterLambda = Expression.Lambda(filterBody, entityParam);
            }               

            entityType.SetQueryFilter(filterLambda);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code to get all entities and filter a property:

```
foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            if (entityType.ClrType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AuditableAttribute), true).Length > 0)
            {                                       
                modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.Name).Property<bool>("IsRemoved");                   
            }

            var isActiveProperty = entityType.FindProperty("IsRemoved");
            if (isActiveProperty != null && isActiveProperty.ClrType == typeof(bool))
            {
                var entityBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType);
                var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "e");
                var methodInfo = typeof(EF).GetMethod(nameof(EF.Property))!.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(bool))!;
                var efPropertyCall = Expression.Call(null, methodInfo, parameter, Expression.Constant("IsRemoved"));
                var body = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, efPropertyCall, Expression.Constant(false));
                var expression = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
                entityBuilder.HasQueryFilter(expression);
            }                
        }
```