# Applying global filtering to all the classes that are inheriting from a base class in ASP.NET Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection, entity-framework-core

I am trying to implement a global filtering for some entities that are inheriting from a BaseEntity. And I want this filtering to be somehow automatic. So what I am doing is:
I am getting all the inheriting classes:

```
IEnumerable<BaseEntity> exporters = typeof(BaseEntity)
            .Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseEntity)) && !t.IsAbstract)
            .Select(t => (BaseEntity)Activator.CreateInstance(t));
            List<BaseEntity> listEntities = exporters.ToList<BaseEntity>();
```

Until here it is working I am getting all the sub-classes. Now I want to apply some filter on those classes, but I can't find a way to achieve that.
Based on the below code:

```
builder.Entity<Might need some Reflection here to get the class>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsDeleted);
```

Not so sure if it something doable or should I go on the manual way?

Comment: I was writing an answer but the question got closed. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68503299/5298150