# Dynamic EF Linq Join Navigation Properties by using Reflection,Memberexpressions or anything

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core, delegates

I'm trying to create a global query filter for entity framework(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters)

And I'm wanting to apply a custom left join on every entity in my dbcontext. Now then the difficulties for this come with the table join(https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-joining-operator-join) because the key selector for inner/outer sequence seem to HAVE to be the same type(int, string ect).

However if I hardcode my join like below:

```
standardList,  // inner sequence 
student => student.StandardID,    // outerKeySelector
standard => standard.StandardID,  // innerKeySelector
(student, standard) => new  // result selector
{
StudentName = student.StudentName,
StandardName = standard.StandardName
});
```

We have no problems because the key selectors are both navigation propertys of the same type(int). Great! However,

For my application i'm inserting into a dictionary the following:
Entity, The Navigation property(EG: Student.Parent.Id).
This is stored in my dictionary as type: Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> for each Entity which I register like so:

`Class().Register<Person, int>(x => x.Parent.Id)`

I would then like to able to loop all the entities by using this:[Using Global Query Filters for all entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65702049/using-global-query-filters-for-all-entities)

However the difficulties arising in my implementation is I can't find a way to swap in and out the key selector as we loop over them because they are stored as different entity types which means when I try to reference the expression it can't join because they have two different types ie Entity, Entity.(Even though that BOTH properties ARE the same type(int). I have hoped that a memberexpression could potentially help but i've had no luck with them and also no luck with creating a lambda expression.

I've tried examples(sudo):

```
var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "x");
var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(x, "Id");
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person,int>>(body, x);

Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> test = x => dbset<Person>.Join( dbset<Parent>, 
b => lambda , c => lambda 
(b, cda) => new {b, cda})
.Where(y => y.Person.Id == 1).Any()
)

var testb = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty("Id");

//I know this would join to itself but would at least join for a test. Compiles but the query cant' be translated exception probably because it says the outer and inner joins are: (object)(int)(PropertyInfo)Int32 Id.GetValue() which I dont think translate like it says
Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> test = x => dbset<Person>.Join( dbset<Parent>, 
b => (int)testb.GetValue(b, null) , c => (int)testb.GetValue(c, null)
(b, cda) => new {b, cda})
.Where(y => y.Person.Id == 1).Any()
)
```

Its extremely frustrating because I thought this woudn't be so complicated to implement and i've spent days trying to achieve something that on paper sounds simple just replace a hardcoded expression with one I previously created!

I've looked into expressions, memberexpressions, lambda compiling, reflection, delegates but everything on Google is now purple. Can anyone help give me some direction here?

It must be possible to apply a join like the above on all entities based on a stored navigation property

Comment: Stepping back, what are you trying to achieve with a global query filter?

Comment: Basically i'm trying to ensure that the data belongs to a specific user(I dont have a userid on every table so I need to navigate up or down a few tables to get it sometimes) and I need to ensure we don't bring back records for any tables if its not their data. All tables do have do relate to a table which will have a userid on it eventually though. Usually a max of 2 tables away

Comment: And writing separate global query filters for each entity is somehow too difficult?

Comment: I think I'm close by compiling the expression and then passing in the TEntity in on the join, it compiles but I get a LINQ error saying it can't be translated(it doesn't say its the join) but I know it's the join part as it works with a hardcoded join on the same join. So I'm not sure if its possible with the joins translating to :(object)(int)(PropertyInfo)Int32 Id.GetValue()

Comment: Yeah I have hundreds of entities and it seems a bit hacky(DRY violation) having to write the same "query" over and over for all entities

Comment: Well, the alternative should be looking less attractive by now.

Comment: In theory for what im doing the Inner key selector is the only bit changing as the right side is always static for my join.

Comment: So you don't think its possible to register a navigation property on a class and swap them in?

Comment: I don't think it's worth trying.

Comment: Can you think of another way to implement a multitenant check then? It seems all the other designs expect you to have a userid on every table which obliviously isn't good SQL design as it's duplicate data nor does it apply to my table design(not made by me)

Comment: Having the UserID/TenantID as the leading column of every primary key is fine SQL schema design.  It performs fine, and has easily-verified tenant isolation. Alternatively, just hard-code the global query filter for each entity that lacks the UserId.