# Exclude property on update - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, automapper, .net-6.0

I'm trying to make PUT that update a ToDo, and I wanted to preserve the old 'createdAt' field instead of overwriting the database, what's the best way to do it? I'm currently using AutoMapper

```
[HttpPut("{id:int}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ToDoDTO>> Put([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] UpdateToDoDTO updateToDoDTO)
{
    var exists = await unitOfWork.ToDoRepository.Exists(id);
    if (!exists)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    var toDo = mapper.Map<ToDo>(updateToDoDTO);
    toDo.Id = id;
    unitOfWork.ToDoRepository.Update(toDo);
    await unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
    return Ok(mapper.Map<ToDoDTO>(toDo));
}
```

My update DTO doesn't receive a 'createdAt' so that resets the datetime to '0001-01-01T00:00:00'

```
public class UpdateToDoDTO
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required")]
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Completed status is required")]
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class ToDo : BaseEntity
{
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
    public List<Comment>? Comments { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

I have this code to run in 'SaveAsync()' function to update the 'updatedAt' field

```
public async Task SaveAsync()
{
     AddTimestamps();
     await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
private void AddTimestamps()
{
     var entities = context.ChangeTracker
         .Entries()
         .Where(x => x.Entity is BaseEntity && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));
     foreach (var entity in entities)
     {
          if (entity.State == EntityState.Added)
          {
               ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
          }
          ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [Date/time value generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#datetime-value-generation). I've failed to make `ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate` work but for `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` for PostgreSQL the following seems to work just fine:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
    .Property(post => post.CreatedOn)
    .HasDefaultValueSql("now()")
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
    .Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore); // prevents manual overrides
```

Comment: is there any way to use this with a BaseEntity class? otherwise I'll need to write it for every new entity

Comment: @MartinPilaszek you can use `modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()` to "dynamically" setup entities  - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65702049/using-global-query-filters-for-all-entities/65702479#65702479) for inspiration.