# Apply inner global filters in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm with a problem with global filters in relationships.

The global filter apply only when I already took the registers of the database.

I have two classes:

```
public class Company {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}

public class Document {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a global filter to only get active companies:

`modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasQueryFilter(filter => filter.Active);`

The problem is:

I'm doing a query, looking for all the documents with active companies and paging it.

`query.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);`

What happens is that I keep all the documents, bypassing the global filter of active companies. And when I run the query, instead of getting 50 companies on the page, I only get 6.
The query finds 50 documents, 6 with the active company and the other 44 with inactive companies. At the end of the query, it apply the global filter and only have 6 active companies.

What I want, is that when I make the first query, it apply the filter, taking 50 documents only with active companies, ignoring non active companies since the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created query filter only for `Company` if you want to apply filtering to the `Document`s - try specifying one for it:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Document>().HasQueryFilter(d => d.Company.Active);
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a simpler way to solve this, because I have a lot of entities that are relationed to Company and I'd have to do it for all of them, but apparently there is no other simple solution. Thank you.

Comment: @Viniisouza Was glad to help! You can simplify/automate this by using some reflection and dynamic model building - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65702049/using-global-query-filters-for-all-entities/65702479#65702479).