# Add a QueryFilter migration for every class of a base class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, global-query-filter

I have a set of classes that all inherit from a base class, for example;

```
class Blog: EntityBase
{
  string owner {get;set;}
}

class Post: EntityBase{
  Blog blog {get;set;}
  string title {get;set;}
}

abstract class EntityBase{
 long Id {get;set;}
 bool IsArchived {get;set;}
}
```

I want to apply an [EF query filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) to all records that inherit from my `EntityBase` class. When I create my entity migration I get an error:

> Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated.

```
override protected void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(t => t.ClrType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EntityBase))))
    {
    modelBuilder.Entity(
        typeof(EntityBase),
        entity => 
        { 
            entity.HasQueryFilter((EntityBase e) => e.IsArchived == false);
        });
    }
}
```

How else can I apply this change to all records without looping?

---

**NOTE:** I'm already doing this in the loop and it works OK:

```
foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(t => t.ClrType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EntityBase))))
{
    modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.Name, x => {
        x.Property(nameof(EntityBase.IsArchived))
                            .HasDefaultValue(false);
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something like this, without the `foreach` loop? `modelBuilder.Entity<EntityBase>(entity => entity.HasQueryFilter(e => e.IsArchived == false));`

Comment: Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76288920/10646316) for this duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the base entity class directly when configuring your context. So you can remove the `foreach` loop entirely and do this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityBase>(entity => 
    entity.HasQueryFilter(e => e.IsArchived == false));
```

Comment: This will create `EntityBase` table which may not be desirable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need loop, this should work.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityBase>()
            .HasQueryFilter(e => !e.IsArchived);
```

Comment: This will create `EntityBase` table which may not be desirable.