# Entity Framework Core Configure Base Types automatically

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I have a huge List of inherited classes, currently I need to create for each child class an `IEntityTypeConfiguration` file:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClase()
    {
         Typ = GetType().Name;
    }    

    public string Typ {get; private set;}
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass{}

public class ChildClassConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<ChildClass>
{
   public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ChildClass> builder)
    {
        builder
            .HasBaseType<BaseClass>()
            .HasDiscriminator(b => b.Typ);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to configure that automatically so that the EntityFramework detects and configures all "childClasses"?

Comment: How would that work? The devil is likely in the documentation -and there are drawbacks. There is to my knowledge to do that reliably to start with.

Comment: I hoped that it could work with reflection e.g. Swashbuckle also does that on generating the swagger documentation. ```typeof(SomeBaseClass).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(baseType));```

Comment: Nope, how would it find the discriminators? How would it do other logical things?

Comment: ok. The descriminator is always a property in the base class so I should have access.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to just to create a base generic configuration and :

```cs
public abstract class ChildClassConfigurationBase<T> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    protected virtual void ConfigureCustom(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder)
    {
        
    }
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder)
    {
        builder
            .HasBaseType<BaseClass>()
            .HasDiscriminator(b => b.Typ);
        ConfigureCustom(builder);
    }
}
```

And then just inherit it for all child classes - `ChildClassConfiguration : ChildClassConfigurationBase<ChildClass>`. Another option is to do something similar to [Using Global Query Filters for all entities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65702049/2501279):

```
foreach (var mutableEntityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    // check if current entity type is child of BaseModel
    if (mutableEntityType.ClrType.IsAssignableTo(typeof(BaseClass)) && mutableEntityType.ClrType != typeof(BaseClass))
    {
        var method = typeof(WhatsNewContext)
            .GetMethod(nameof(ConfigureChildOfBaseClass), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static) // todo: get method
            .MakeGenericMethod(mutableEntityType.ClrType);
        method.Invoke(null, new object?[] { modelBuilder });
    }
}
public static void ConfigureChildOfBaseClass<T>(ModelBuilder builder) where T : BaseClass
{
    builder
        .Entity<T>()
        .HasBaseType<BaseClass>()
        .HasDiscriminator(b => b.Typ);
}
```