# Map existing fields to a complex type in EFCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, complextype

is it possible to take an existing table and map it to an object containing a complex type.

For example:

Table Customer has several address columns but they are simply named AddressLine1, AddressLine2, etc.  Not Customer_AddressLine1.  Is there a way to still map those fields to a complex type?

For example:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FirstName { get; set; }

    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
}
```

would become:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FirstName { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public record Address(string Line1, string Line2);
```

Comment: A complex type is a CLASS.  Change RECORD to CLASS.

Comment: Read this section [Mapping owned types with table splitting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#mapping-owned-types-with-table-splitting), it has sample how to map to specific columns.

Comment: Why not make table ```Addresses``` and map many addresses to ```Customer``` ?

Comment: It's just an example, we have an existing database and I'm seeing if we can get creative with mapping to our entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to provide the column names manually (assuming you are using EF 8 with it's complex types, the same can be done with [owned entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#mapping-owned-types-with-table-splitting)):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    .ComplexProperty(entity => entity.Address, builder =>
    {
        builder.Property(c => c.Line1).HasColumnName("AddressLine1");
        builder.Property(c => c.Line2).HasColumnName("AddressLine2");
    });
```

Other options would be to mess with [interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors) and/or `IMutableModel` (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65702049/using-global-query-filters-for-all-entities/65702479#65702479))